# MySQL disable & enable keys

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my MySQL database,  there is a table which has 2,000,000 records. Now, I would like to insert another 6,000,000 new records into this table.

To speed up the insertion, I though I should use disable/enable keys like following:

```
ALTER TABLE cars DISABLE KEYS;

INSERT INTO cars ...
...
...
INSERT INTO cars ...

ALTER TABLE search_all_values ENABLE KEYS;

OPTIMIZE TABLE cars;
```

But I somehow feel that, the disable/enable keys would make more sense to be used for empty table insertion.

While in my case, I have already 2,000,000 records in the table, when `ENABLE KEYS`, mysql will re-create all the indexes (including the existing records and new added records) which probably won't produce a efficient data insertion as a whole in my case. **As re-create all the indexes will take long time** and probably so does `OPTIMIZE TABLE`

I would like to ask your opinion about am I right and how can I have a efficent data insertion in my case?

Comment: Are you certain that key update is a bottleneck ?

Comment: That's is my worry and there is someone has the same worry here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,68820,68939#msg-68939

Comment: Anyways, those indexes will be created once you enable them again. Try doing a bul insert rather than row/row and also do a update statistics and see if that improves anything.

Comment: Rahul, what do you mean about bul insertion and update statistics?

Comment: Bulk insert, when multiple rows are inserted in a one INSERT statement.

Comment: Is optimizing table necessary after data insertion in my case?

Answer (score 62):

You definitely have to pick your approach based on the engine type... optimizing [for MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html) or [for InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

We recently ran a benchmark comparing different ways to insert data and measured the time from before insertion and until all indices are fully restored. It was on an empty table, but we used up to 10 million rows.

MyISAM with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE/DISABLE KEYS` won hands down in our test (on a Windows 7 system, MySQL 5.5.27 - now we're trying it on a Linux system).

ENABLE and DISABLE KEYS does not work for InnoDB, it's MyISAM only. For InnoDB, use `SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;` if you are sure your data doesn't contain duplicates (don't forget to set them to `1` after the upload is complete).

I don't think you need `OPTIMIZE TABLE` after a bulk insert - MySQL rows are ordered by insertion and the index is rebuilt anyway. There's no "extra fragmentation" by doing a bulk insert.

Feel free to comment if I made factual errors.

**UPDATE:** According to our more recent and complete test results, the advice to DISABLE / ENABLE keys is wrong.

A coworker had a program run multiple different tests - a table with InnoDB / MyISAM prefilled and empty, selection and insertions speeds with `LOAD DATA LOCAL`, `INSERT INTO`, `REPLACE INTO` and `UPDATE`, on "dense" and "fragmented" tables (I'm not quite sure how, I think it was along the lines of `DELETE FROM ... ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ...` with a fixed seed so it's still comparable) and enabled and diasabled indices.

We tested it with many different MySQL versions (5.0.27, 5.0.96, 5.1.something, 5.5.27, 5.6.2) on Windows and Linux (not the same versions on both OS, though). MyISAM only won when the table was empty. InnoDB was faster when data was present already and generally performed better (except for hdd-space - MyISAM is smaller on disk).

Still, to really benefit from it, you have to test it yourself - with different versions, different configuration settings and a lot of patience - especially regarding weird inconsistencies (5.0.97 was a lot faster than 5.5.27 with the same config - we're still searching the cause). **What we did find was** that `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS` are next to worthless and sometimes harmfull if you don't start with an empty table.

Comment: This is a really fantastic answer. Thank you for your thorough research!

Comment: Hmm, good effort, but I would doubt the conclusion since wouldn't the great variationsin test results be indicative that there's **a lot** of unknown factors here?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing the new keys will take up some time. It's up to you to decide if you want it to be done all at once (disabling it first) or one at a time (by keeping it as-is and letting it index as each record is being added)

I'd go for the latter, not disabling your keys. If you fear stressing the server to much, you could try inserting in batches, e.g. only a certain amount of inserts per minute.

Comment: @ mlitn, how about optimize the table after data insertion, is this step necessary?