# Duplicate PRIMARY_KEY in WP database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have a site built on top of Wordpress 3.7.1. Using a plugin I do a DB backup but then when I try to import that DB at development server I get this error:

> ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 9480: Duplicate entry '2280' for key
>   'PRIMARY'

How is that possible? I mean how in DB duplicates can exists? How I can fix this?

Comment: Which tools do you use for the backup and its import exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way you created your development server. Please follow this steps:

1. Login to your local "phpMyAdmin" to export your private CMS database.
2. Replace each old URL address with the new domain address.
3. Create a new database for your development server
4. Login to the "phpMyAdmin" for your new database. Under the "Import" tab, select the file you just downloaded, changed and saved.

Comment: And as I said in previous post comment this is the same procedure I follow to export/import the script I just don't know how if `id` is `PRIMARY KEY` and have `AUTOINCREMENT` can be duplicates, this is very rare, any other advice

Comment: [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) is triggered only by 0 and NULL. [`PRIMARY KEY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) is unique by definition, moreover it is `NOT NULL`. See the docs.

Answer (score 0):

How does your backup look like? I suspect it being a sequence of `INSERT`s. When you development server already has an old dump imported, the old and new values will be in conflict. You should drop the old database and recreate it from scratch.

Comment: This is how I did in first any time I tried, just the empty DB is created and the second step after that was import the SQL script but without success

Comment: @Reynier Please provide schema of the table. `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;` Primary key really forces unique values. Only way to insert duplicate values into such a column is bypassing the key check, e.g. via [`ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE KEYS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html) (edit: does not work) or [maybe other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8210608/2157640). See also this [post in MySQL mailing list](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/195015). Probably looking for the value `2280` in your production database and its backup will shed more light on the problem.