# How can I import very large csv file into mysql fastly?

Tags: mysql, performance, csv, import, row

If I have for example 1 GB of csv file and I want to import it to mysql fastly, what should I do? I've try before to import 1 GB file and it took about 1,5 hours long. I use computer with 16 GB of RAM. If I want to upload the larger file it will takes more long time.

So, what should I do to faster the process?
Thanks....

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE SQL statement.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could temporarily disable key/indexes(for MyISAM) to the tables involved

```
ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE/DISABLE KEYS
```

or set AUTO_COMMIT to off for InnoDB.

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
```

and then run LOAD DATA INFILE

NB: one thing to note here is, source file residing on the same host could  help us with performance as the data don't have to travel over network. In short use LOAD DATA INFILE not LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

You could take a ref from this well elaborated answer:
[MySQL disable & enable keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210608/mysql-disable-enable-keys)

Comment: oooo thanks, but what's the difference between LOAD DATA INFILE AND LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE? And if use LOAD DATA INFILE is faster than use mysqlimport tools?

Comment: the only difference is locating the file, either from LOCAL mysql client(the files travel through over network) or residing on the same server host. I believe all imports tools internally run LOAD DATA INFILE to the server.

Comment: Oooooo thanks a lot, but how how fast is it? How many records per minute? Hahaahah if you know tell me

Answer (score 0):

Put the MySQL database on a faster disk.

Databases tend to be IO limited, so if you want a faster database you should put it on faster disk hardware.

What's the disk storage for your data?  A SATA drive?  That will handle at most 50-70 IO operations per second.

Comment: Yes, I use the SATA disk. But, I mean, how can I make the database operation like multiply row as fast as I multiply general text file. I've multiplied content of the text files till it become 1 GB, and it very fast. I use ubuntu cat operation and append it to specified file till 1 GB. So, why the database cannot fast as I append on ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Databases do IO differently - they tend to do IO in ways that the data is **guaranteed** to be correctly written to the disk.  When you do IO, your "successful" write may very well be cached in memory somewhere and not actually written to the disk.  @avishek's answer will reduce the number of IO transactions the database makes to disk, making it run faster.  But it will still be limited by how fast your disk is.  Or in the case of a SATA disk, how **slow** it is, especially if it's a 5400-RPM slow one.