# How to improve mysql INSERT query efficiency where there are large no of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have googled but didn't found any effective solution. I am having one small php file where only two `INSERT` queries are there (different tables). One table having around `3358500` rows and other table having around `679570` rows. I think because of large number of rows it's getting very slow for insertion.

I though of using these:
i) stored procedure (may not be effective in this case)
ii) Using Transaction

**Note: Using InnoDB engine

Please provide me some other solutions apart from above two. Thanks!

Comment: why down vote? OK , down vote is ok. But .. If I am wrong just point me out. Or give some solution.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that the number of records in your tables influence `insert` performance? Do you run expenive triggers or something like that?

Comment: That would be more mysql optimisation like double write disable,foreignkey verification disabled and increasing your buffer size :)

Comment: @flowit I don't have idea. I though may be because of that. What could be the other reason? I am not sure :(

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun .. Can you please explain little bit.

Comment: Please show your table schemas and constraints if there are any.

Comment: @SaribanD'Cl This could help you: https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts

Comment: @flowit : 
CREATE TABLE `url_track` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `email` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `url` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3358511 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun .. I'll try to improvise accordingly. and will check after this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are few possibilities of having slow insert. Some are already stated in the comments , Still let me write out again.

1) Make sure you are doing extended insert when you are doing a bulk insert. IT will significantly make your query quicker.
2) You might have some triggers on table which might slow down the insert.
3) You might have many indexes on the table , Indexes are proven to make mysql slow and that that is why there are few ways by which we can handle it .

- Enable Transaction - So that index will be build at the end of transaction.
- Disable indexes / keys temporary. Once your insertion is done you may enable it. here is the relevant answer about the same.

[MySQL disable & enable keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210608/mysql-disable-enable-keys)

Comment: ya.. I'll try like this. I have found some similar solution here http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/