# MySQL is very slow with 19500 insert?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, prestashop-1.6

I have an prestashop online, and since 1 month, we have some too long response times.

- MySQL: 5.5
- All tables(Engine): MyIsam
- PHP: 7.0 * / 5.6

I import some csv file with 20 000 lines and when i'am in dev env. it takes 40 secondes and in production [ Tie well ] 10 minutes.

We have removed the material cause, cache , ans charge cause. -> [MySQL has treat 5 billion of requests in 45 seconds -> prod machine].

Actually the export sql file is 1.3 Go -> in prod.

We use Prestashop Db class to do the request.

If you have any suggestion !!

Thanks !!

Comment: Your mysql server can handle one hundred million requests per second? And even more impressive: you have a shop that has so many customers that you have to serve 5 billion requests in less than a minute?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ISAM you may disable indexes before insert.

See [MySQL disable & enable keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210608/mysql-disable-enable-keys)