# Insert 20K records in 3 tables with validation in less time

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 tables `customers`, `customer_address` and `customer_org` with 20K records and I want to insert a new record
with checking `'Email'` of new record with table customers `'Email'` attribute already exist or not.

To insert 17K records it is taking **1Hr 21Min**.

I'm inserting a new record in all 3 tables, if the new record Email does not exist in customers table.
So is there any solution to reduce this time?

I'm using Laravel framework.

Database: mysql innodb

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844438/4604701 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361368/4604701

Comment: Your solution looks optimal, but then again, we can't see your solution, so how would we know?

Comment: what does your insert code/query look like?

Comment: Best solution is to create a job.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
1> create a **cron job** for it which automatically takes care of it without user intervention.

2>Use **SAS** disk or **SSD's** for MySQL database.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what your schema is including it's constraints and indexes or what your actual queries / statements are.
It's impossible to answer your question without this information, and without any profiling data.

You would do well to read up on [MySql Profiling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html), as this will help you to find out what is going on with your queries / statements.

If I were to hazard a guess, however, I would guess that the 'customers.email' column is not properly indexed.