# Batch processing files and diff with database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, batch-processing

Currently I am developing a Spring-Boot application that is periodically trying to process a file containing user data where every line contains `userId` and `departamentId` separated by `|` for example `123534|13`. That file will be containing few milions of records.

My requirement is to load this data into mysql database in such manner that:

- If the user with processed ID exists, **do not do anything**
- If the user is not existing **create** new user
- If the user is not on the list but is present in the database, **remove it**
- If department with current is not present on the database, **create it**

I have made some optimization like

- Caching Departaments to fill entity
- Batch collecting Users to Save and saving it throuch `JpaRepository` `saveAll` method

But Still I am making too many database calls to the database, I am checking if user is present in order to create entity for save for every record...

My Entities are rather simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "departaments")
public class Departament{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departament_id")
    private Departament departament;
```

**Has anyone come across problem like that?**

**Could it be optimized more?**

**Is there any good pattern for processing?**

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things here:

1. It would seem your primary source of truth for users is the CSV file. Why not simply truncate and recreate the `USER` table? You may run into some problems (I understand that referential integrity is *not* one of them in your scenario - or is it?), but you'll get user deletion for free (TBH I can't quite picture how you handle user deletion in the current setup). It would run even faster [with key checks disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210608/mysql-disable-enable-keys)
2. Are you actually seeing performance improvements when using `saveAll`? This does not limit the number of `SELECT` statements to execute
3. Are you sure you're operating on the right level of abstraction? Perhaps you could use plain JDBC instead of JPA. with JPA, there will be a lot of caching/mapping involved, causing significant overhead. With JDBC you could leverage MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements to get what you want
4. If you go for any of the above, you could try using [Spring Batch](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-batch-tutorial-writing-information-to-a-database-with-jdbc/) for more declarative processing

Answer (score 4):

If it is a "replacement", do this to avoid any downtime:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE old;
LOAD DATA INFILE ... (and any other massaging)
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

If it is a "delta", the `LOAD` it into a separate table, then execute suitable SQL statements to perform the updates.  It would be approximately one SQL statement per bullet item in your Question.  No loops.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to do it simply using Spring-batch

**context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- stored job-meta in database -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**database.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- connect to database -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="User@1234" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

</beans>
```

**jobReport.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="report" class="com.om.model.Report" scope="prototype" />

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter"
                    commit-interval="2">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

        <!-- Read a csv file -->
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:cvs/report.csv" />

        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="userId,departmentId" />
                    </bean>
                </property>

                <property name="fieldSetMapper">

                    <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->
                    <!--
                        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
                    -->

                    <!-- map to an object -->
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                    </bean>

                </property>

            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into RAW_REPORT(userId,departmentId) values (:userId, :departmentId)
            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**App.java**  It's main class for your job execution

```
package com.om;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException {

        String[] springConfig  = 
            {   "spring/batch/config/database.xml", 
                "spring/batch/config/context.xml",
                "spring/batch/jobs/job-report.xml" 
            };

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

        try {

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    }
}
```

**Report.java** it's your Pojo

```
package com.om.model;

public class Report {

    private String userId;
    private String departmentId;
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }
    public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }


}
```

Now you need to put your report.csv into resource folder having millions of userId & departmentId.

You can simply see your database tables how job is executed along with database entries automatically.
Please ask for any help required.