# Is it better to use MySQL or Java for bulk operations on Parent table and foreign key table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

In my Spring Boot app, every hour I'm getting new Parent and Child data from a response that I need to update the db with. The response can contain new Parents, new Children, existing Parents with updates and if a Parent and/or Child is not present in the response, they need to be deleted from db.

This all needs to happen in a single transaction to avoid race conditions.

I have a Parent table like below:

```
Parent table
id | name | age | email | child_id
----------------------------------
```

And a Child table with a foreign key to Parent:

```
Child table
id | parent_id | name
---------------------
```

And a Mapping table

```
id | parent_id | child_id
-------------------------
```

1.) First approach is to insert on duplicate 'name' update all new Parent data, then insert the new Child data, then delete all Child data that is not contained in the response, then finally delete all Parent data that is not contained in the response

Something like:

```
//For each new parent run native query

INSERT INTO PARENT (name) VALUES (name, age, email)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE name=name, age=age, email=email;

//For each new child insert with native query

INSERT INTO CHILD (name) VALUES (name)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE name=name

//Remove old Child data

DELETE FROM CHILD WHERE name not in (new_child_name_list);

//Remove old Parent Data

DELETE FROM Parent WHERE name not in (new_parent_name_list);
```

To speed things up and batch, I'd be maintaining my own transaction in the EntityManager and running the above sequence. I'm worried about performance and if some of these operations can be combined. I also don't know how I could set the mapping just using native queries

2.) I get all data from db and do all the logic in Java myself.

```
public void refresh(List<Parent> newParents, List<Child> newChildren) {

    //EntityManager transaction logic here
    List<ParentEntity> oldParents = parentRepo.findAll();
    List<ChildEntity> oldChildren = childRepo.findAll();

    for(ParentEntity oldParent : oldParents) {
        if (/* old matches a new parent */) {
            //update matching old parent to new parent
            //add associated children to parent before save
        } else {
            // no match, delete old parent
        }
    }

}
```

Is it better to have several sql operations with native queries, or handle the majority of the work in java?

EDIT: Many-to-many relationship clarity

Comment: You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981821/batch-processing-files-and-diff-with-database/50107539) useful, it features a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can take cascading operation with Hibernate or other ORM tool easily. I don't think it is a good idea to sync in DB side as well.

please refer to [here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/)

```java
Query q = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :stockCode ");
q.setParameter("stockCode", "4715");
Stock stock = (Stock)q.list().get(0);
session.delete(stock);
```

Comment: The same child can reference different parents. Wouldn't cascade remove the child from the DB and thus for all the other parents as well?